# Does the "Load" statement in Qlikview not permit multiple sequential operations on a field?

Tags: data-visualization, qlikview, qliksense

I would like to preserve the fieldnames: Country, Cal_Year and Cal_Month. However, the code wouldn't run if I tried running it so as written in the following sample code.
Error states: 'Country' is not a valid fieldname.

```
LOAD [Country Code], 
         [ISO code], 
         Currency,
         ApplyMap('Currency_Map',Currency, 'Currency Unmapped') as Country, 
         Quotation, 
         year as Cal_Year, 
         trim(mid(period, 3,4)) as Cal_Month, 
         Balance, 
         Activity,
         (Balance/Quotation) as FX_Rate,
         Country & Cal_Year & Cal_Month as Key1   <-supposedly an erroneous statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing comma?

```
(Balance/Quotation) as FX_Rate,  <-- missing comma here
Country & Cal_Year & Cal_Month as Key1
```

Comment: The missing comma's just a typo in this version, not in the actual code.

Comment: got it. You cant reference the new fields like this (in the same load). You need to write it in `preceding load`. `Load *, Field1 & Field2 as Field3; Load Field1, Field2 Resident MyTable;` You can "nest" as much preceding loads as you want/need. More on the preceding load https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/2.1/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/preceding-load.htm

Answer (score 1):

Also to do it this way you can only reference the original data table, not the results. So you need

```
Country & Cal_Year & Cal_Month as Key1
```

to become

```
ApplyMap('Currency_Map',Currency, 'Currency Unmapped')
& year
& trim(mid(period, 3,4)) as Key
```

for it to work after adding the comma as well

Comment: But I also need the fieldnames: Country, Cal_
Year and Cal_Month for further use.

Comment: That's fine, just add them as you were doing. My line only replaces the statement for creating the key. You can use the same field as many times as you like in a single load. You just can't call fields in the statement that is creating them